Airflow DockerOperator: argument list too long
The Problem:
I've a DAG wherere I basically launch a docker Container with a bunch of volumes and environment variables.
One of these Environment variables is a Json String that must be computed with Python Code and then supplied to the DockerOperator. This JSON String serves as a configuration to some application.
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator


default_args = {
'owner'                 : 'airflow',
'description'           : 'Test',
'start_date'            : datetime(2024, 5, 1),
}

def some_function():
    # Here is the logic to generate the HUGE dynamic JSON String
    json_string = "..."
    return json_string

with DAG('docker_operator_demo', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="5 * * * *", catchup=False) as dag:
    example_task = DockerOperator(
        task_id='run_my_app',
        image='my_docker_img',
        container_name='my_app',
        api_version='auto',
        auto_remove=True,
        command="echo run_my_app",
        docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
        network_mode="bridge",
        environment={
            "MY_APP_CONFIG": some_function()
        }
    )

    example_task


The problem is that this JSON String is huge sometimes (like 200+ keys where each values is 1000 characters+). When the JSON is this huge, I've this error argument list too long.
I understand where this error comes from, it's just that the env variables exceeds the UNIX limit.
Possible solution:
I've thought about supplying this "dynamically computed" JSON string as a volume mount to the DockerOperator but I can't find a proper way to do this.
The Question:
With Airflow, is it possible to dynamically create a file and supply it as a volume to the docker operator ? If yes, can you please share an example ?

I never worked on  DockerOperator, but I think following some times help you, create a create the file(may using a task or python operator) , and then send the file location to  DockerOperator, environment.
And later can delete old files using another dag.

Chrek host_tmp_dir or tmp_dir   can be used anyway.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html.
Also check set  ulimits (list[docker.types.Ulimit] | None)  fixes the issue

@Jisson If I create I file within some_function, it will probaby get executed by the dag processor and not the executor so not sure this will help.
I'm not sure ulimits will help because the arg lenght is limited by unix so can't do much for this :/

task_create_file  >>  example_task  helps??
